# Porque no muestra los valores?

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente objeto en javascript, pero no me muestra ningún valor, ni nombre, ni edad, ni el monedero, cual es el error?

```js
// El jugador
function Jugador(name, edad, dinero) {
  
  this.name = name;
  this.edad = edad;
  this.dinero = dinero;
   
}

function obtenerNombre() {  // Obtengo el nombre del input
  
  var obtenerN = document.getElementById("nombre").value;
  obtenerN.toString();
  
  return obtenerN;
  
}
function obtenerEdad() { // Obtengo la edad del input
  
  var obtenerE = document.getElementById("edad").value;
  obtenerE = parseInt(obtenerE);
  
  return obtenerE;
}
function crearJugador() { // Creo el jugador , pasando como parametro las funciones para obtener nombre y edad, y por ultimo 0 por defecto en el monedero.
  
  new Jugador(obtenerNombre(), obtenerEdad(), 0);
  document.write(Jugador.nombre, Jugador.edad, Jugador.monedero); // Escribo todos los datos del jugador
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Start your code here -->

  <style>
    body {
      
      background-color: #111111;
    }
   h1 {
      
      color: white;
  }
   
    
  </style>
  <form>
<input type="text" id="nombre" placeHolder="Nombre"/>
    <input type="text" id="edad" placeholder="edad"/>
    <input type="button" onClick="obtenerNombre(); obtenerEdad(); crearJugador();" value="Enviar mis datos!"/>
    
  </form>
  
  

<!-- End your code here -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Donde quieres mostrar la información?

Comment: fijate en la funcion crearJugador

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes varios errores en tu código:

- A la hora de que quieres imprimir las propiedades de tu clase `Jugador`hay dos que están mal escritas: `Jugador.nombre` la correcta es `Jugador.name` y `Jugador.monedero` la correcta es `Jugador.dinero`
- Tienes que inicializar tu clase dentro de una variable para que puedas acceder a sus atributos, de lo contrario al accederlos de la forma en que lo haces siempre te devolverá valores indefinidos.
- No es necesario mandar llamar tus métodos de `obtenerNombre` y `obtenerEdad` en el click del botón, ya que eso ya lo haces mediante la función `crearJugador`
- `obtenerN.toString()` está demás, porque `value` ya te devuelve un string.

Te dejo el Snippet funcionando, y ya imprime los valores que capturas desde tu forma.

Saludos

```js
function Jugador(name, edad, dinero) {
  
  this.name = name;
  this.edad = edad;
  this.dinero = dinero;
   
}

function obtenerNombre() {  // Obtengo el nombre del input
  
  var obtenerN = document.getElementById("nombre").value;
  return obtenerN;
  
}
function obtenerEdad() { // Obtengo la edad del input
  
  var obtenerE = document.getElementById("edad").value;
  obtenerE = parseInt(obtenerE);
  
  return obtenerE;
}

function crearJugador() {
  
  var jug = new Jugador(obtenerNombre(), obtenerEdad(), 0);
  document.write(jug.name, jug.edad, jug.dinero);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Start your code here -->

  <style>
    body {
      
      background-color: #111111;
    }
   h1 {
      
      color: white;
  }
   
    
  </style>
  <form>
<input type="text" id="nombre" placeHolder="Nombre"/>
    <input type="text" id="edad" placeholder="edad"/>
    <input type="button" onClick="obtenerNombre(); obtenerEdad(); crearJugador();" value="Enviar mis datos!"/>
    
  </form>
  
  

<!-- End your code here -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Entonces el error estaba en colocarlo en una variable, pero un problema.. si el primer jugador crea su jugador y luego viene un segundo jugador, este ultimo reemplazará los valores del primer jugador? ando desorientado

Comment: y podrias darme la fuente de donde dice que debo asociar a una variable para acceder a la clase porfavor

Comment: Eso ya sería otro tipo de implementación, como guardar cada jugador en un arreglo de jugadores, se me ocurre de manera rápida.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Classes

Answer (score 0):

Son varios problemas, el id de edad es edad no nombre, debe ser:

```
 <input type="text" id="edad" placeholder="edad"/>
```

Puedes únicamente llamar el método `crearJugador()` en lugar de :

```
obtenerNombre(); obtenerEdad(); crearJugador();"
```

ya que `crearJugador()` llama los demás métodos.

Debes revisar las variables que usas ya que no son las mismas.

---

```js
// El jugador
function Jugador(nombre, edad, dinero) {
  
  this.nombre = nombre;
  this.edad = edad;
  this.dinero = dinero;
   
}

function obtenerNombre() {  // Obtengo el nombre del input      
  var obtenerN = document.getElementById("nombre").value;
  return obtenerN;
  
}
function obtenerEdad() { // Obtengo la edad del input      
  var obtenerE = document.getElementById("edad").value;
  return  parseInt(obtenerE);    
}

function crearJugador() { // Creo el jugador , pasando como parametro las funciones para obtener nombre y edad, y por ultimo 0 por defecto en el monedero.
  
  var jugador = new Jugador(obtenerNombre(), obtenerEdad(), 0);
  document.write("nombre: " + jugador.nombre + " ,edad: " + jugador.edad + " , dinero: " + jugador.dinero); // Escribo todos los datos del jugador     
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Start your code here -->

  <style>
    body {
      
      background-color: #111111;
    }
   h1 {
      
      color: white;
  }
   
    
  </style>
  <form>
<input type="text" id="nombre" placeHolder="nombre"/>
    <input type="text" id="edad" placeholder="edad"/>
    <input type="button" onClick="crearJugador();" value="Enviar mis datos!"/>
    
  </form>
  
  

<!-- End your code here -->
</body>
</html>
```